# Can I validate that a string is a valid date in Presto

Tags: presto, treasure-data

I would like to check if a sales_date field is a valid date before trying to parse out the month in a select query:

Right now, I am doing this: and the query errors out if the sales_date is not a valid date

`SELECT CAST(YEAR(DATE(sales_date)) from sales`

I'd like to do something like `CASE sales_date is a valid date` to prevent erroring the query if just one row is invalid.

But can't find a presto function that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try) which will return null if date conversion fails:

```
WITH dataset(ts) AS (
    values 
        ('2021-08-22'),
        ('2021-08-22'),
        ('2021-22-08'),
        ('not a date')
)

select try(date(ts))
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-08-22 |
| 2021-08-22 |
|  |
|  |